# c++ Compiling/Executing MakeFiles

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I recently downloaded a project of github that I found really interesting. I was reading the description about the project and it said the following - "Run make and then use the resulting executable 123.exe." So I opened Visual Studio but there is no compile/debug button, Just "select a startup item. I have tried googling but i cant understand how to compile it and the reason behind the "MakeFile" I did try to compile as google said through Visual Studio Command Line and got the following

> makefile(1) : fatal error U1033: syntax error : '=' unexpectedStop.

Also the source code of the makefile below.

```
    TARGET:=revp

SOURCES:=./sources
HEADERS:=./headers

ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),build)
    BUILD:=./build
else ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug)
    BUILD:=./build/debug
else
    BUILD:=./build
endif

CC:=g++
CFLAGS:=-I$(HEADERS) -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lpthread

CFILES:=$(shell find $(SOURCES) -printf '%P ' -name '*.cpp')
OFILES:=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(BUILD)/%.o,$(CFILES))

.PHONY: build debug clean mkdir
.DEFAULT_GOAL:=build

build: CFLAGS+=-O3
build: mkdir $(OFILES)
    $(CC) $(OFILES) -o $(TARGET).exe $(CFLAGS)

debug: CFLAGS+=-O0 -ggdb -D DEBUG
debug: mkdir $(OFILES)
    $(CC) $(OFILES) -o $(TARGET).debug.exe $(CFLAGS)

mkdir:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD)
    rm -f $(TARGET).exe
    rm -f $(TARGET).debug.exe

$(OFILES): $(BUILD)/%.o: $(SOURCES)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: There's no simple way to use makefiles with VS. The easiest solution is to download MSYS2, install Make and GCC from its package manager, then run `make` from MSYS2 shell.

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/jafarlihi/revp) is the project you are talking about then there is a remark about building it on Windows: "_Note: revp also builds on Windows. Just create a new Visual Studio project and import the files._"